# Raphael: Improving Range of Path Onclick

Tags: javascript, raphael

I have a project I'm working on that creates a graph that looks like this: [image: Graph Snip]

There is a functionality of the original app that I'm rewriting into web where you can click near the black paths and it will select that path, as indicated by the one path that is noticeably thicker.

I managed to get the `onclick` for the black paths working, but I'm finding the range to which you can select these lines is far too small (it's pixel perfect), and would make the feature worthless.

Is there a way I can expand the range at which you can click a path? Even 5 pixels on each side would help immensely.

My current line of thinking is to make significantly thicker white paths beneath the black paths and use their `onclick`, but while I'm testing that out I figured I'd ask if there's some other (hopefully easier) way that's not clear to me that someone else might know. I haven't seen anything within the Raphael documentation that does what I need, but of course if there is something I missed I'd love to see it. Any ideas are appreciated.

Comment: I don't think there is, and you're on the correct lines with drawing thicker paths. (no pun intended)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [Ian](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1429053/ian) for confirming my suspicions, this is what I ended up doing:

```js
this.line = canvas.path(this.lineString);
this.selectionLine = canvas.path(this.lineString); 

this.selectionLine.attr('stroke-width', 15);
this.selectionLine.attr('stroke-linecap', 'round');
this.selectionLine.attr('opacity', 0);
this.selectionLine.toFront();
```

The `attr('stroke-linecap', 'round')` bit gives the path ends a curved portion so if you click just above a path it'll still count. Likely unnecessary, but I feel it important to account for possible user frustration.

It's important that you verify that the selection path is in fact drawing above the display path, otherwise if the user does manage to click the display path's area, the selection won't go through. Of course you could just stick the `onclick` onto the display line too, but I feel that drawing the selection path above the other is a cleaner solution.

It looks like this if you remove the `opacity` line, change the color, and change `toFront()` to `toBack()'

[image: Graph Snip]